# MVC 5 request domain url

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

im trying to find the domain url in my MVC controller

```
var currentURL = Request.Url.AbsolutePath ;
```

this is returning /home/index but notthe domain

any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use in my solution

```
var currentURL = Request.Url.Scheme + System.Uri.SchemeDelimiter + Request.Url.Host ;
```

This will return http://www.domain.com

There may be a way to do this better, but this works for me.

Thanks Alan